# Using an input type hidden value to set jsp property

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, select

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function updateInput(initials){
     document.getElementById('test').value = initials;
   };
</script>
```

I call this `onchange` of a `select` dropdown menu.
I get the initials based on what is selected and then save this to a hidden input field.

```
<input type=hidden id=test value=""/>
```

What I want to do now is use this hidden value in my `jsp:setProperty`.

```
<jsp:setProperty property="initials" name="bean" value=" (?) "/>
```

I've tried replacing (?) with `${param.test}` and `${test}` but these don't work without submitting the form.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: hey you want the jsp format or scripting format.

Comment: i'm interested in learning both, so whichever is easier for you :)